# when initializing multidimension array error is given can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, assign

hi friends when I m initializing multidimensional array  I am getting error

**can't convert undefined to object**

when i use push() method to assign value to array element instead of ---> test[i][j]='hi';
then it returns  error => **test[i] undefined**
the only thing i want is to intialize array with some dummy data

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
       // accordian......
            $(function() {
            $( "#accordion1" ).accordion();
        });

        syncMenu(function(group,subgroup,items){
            grp=group;
            sub_groups=subgroup;
            sub_items=items;        
        });
// get data after parsing using ajax
        getPacakage(function(temp){
            sel_pkg_group=temp;
            fillOptionList();
        });
// intailizing array ...        
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<2;j++){
                test[i][j]='hi';
                            test[i][j]='hi';
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test` and `test[]` are undefined, so you'll need to define them first:

```
var test = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    test[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        test[i].push('hi');
    }
}
```

Now you can use `push()` to push values to `test[i]`.